# WMI commands returning error: ClassFactory cannot supply requested class

Tags: cmd, wmic

I try to get Description, DeviceID and VolumeName of USB devices connected to my PC using the following cmd command:

`C:\Users\user>wmic logicaldisk get deviceid, volumename, description`

The output I get is:

> ERROR: ClassFactory cannot supply requested class

On all other machines I've try the request is as expected without the error.

---

Can someone help me please?